# firebaserecycleradapter() cannot be applied to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Can someone please tell what's the error in that specific line.

[image: Here is the image]

Here is the error message showing.

[image: Error Message]

```
package com.example.souravkumar.sqaurewallpapers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Sourav Kumar on 11/3/2017.
 */

public class popular extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder>(
                image_details.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,

                myRef) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, image_details model) {
                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                holder.setUrl(model.getUrl());
            }

            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public static  class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        public void setDate(Long date) {
            textView.setText(date.toString());
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .resize(50, 50)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to the whole code](https://gist.github.com/skumar001997/11bc60477417e674021857b55ad5f0e5)

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code (or of other textual content). Instead edit your question to show the actual code, and include the text of the error message you get. See [Creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok..but can you please help me here? need help

Comment: What version of FirebaseUI are you using and is `image_details` a model class? Please share your code as text and the entire error message you receive.

Comment: firebase Ui: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

Comment: and yes image_details is model class

Comment: @Grimthorr I have updated the error message showing, look into the picture

Comment: @Grimthorr can you please look into my project and tell me where i'm going wrong. I have been struggling from almost a week to retreive data from firebase database to show it on fragment of a tabbed-activity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version (3.x) of FirebaseUI implements a different method of initializing a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` than previous versions. From the [using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter):

> First, configure the adapter by building `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`. In
>   this case we will continue with our chat example:
>
> ```
>  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> options =
>                 new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
>                         .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
>                         .build();
> ```
>
> Next create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` object. You should already
>   have a `ViewHolder` subclass for displaying each item.

So, for your example, you'll need to do something similar to:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<image_details> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<image_details>()
                .setQuery(myRef, image_details.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false);

        return new BlogViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, image_details model) {
        // Bind the image_details object to the BlogViewHolder
        // ...
    }
};
```

Finally, the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call `adapter.startListening()` and `adapter.stopListening()` to stop the listener. It's recommended to call these in `onStart()` and `onStop()` respectively. Further details on this are available in the [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter lifecycle documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle).

Comment: Bind the image_details object how?

Comment: Like you would when creating a normal `RecyclerView`, see [creating lists and cards Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView). So something like: `holder.textView.setText(model.getText());` or whatever method your `image_details` model has for getting the text that you want to display on the row's TextView.

Comment: Sir, I am still not able to get output on my fragment screen. can you please look into my project and tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You missed a method to start the activity.
Add this in `onStart()` method:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello your error is due to a missing argument in these () that are found beside this

```
<image_details, BlogViewHolder>
```

so you missed one more argument of your BlogViewHolder class so I will add the piece of code and refer your missing argument by a comment in this :

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder>(
            image_details.class,
            R.layout.individual_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class //see this is missing so you should add it       
            myRef) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way :

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<image_details> options =
    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<image_details>()
            .setQuery(myRef, image_details.class)
            .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false);

        return new BlogViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, image_details model) {
        // Bind the image_details object to the BlogViewHolder
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and this worked very well for me. Hope it helps someone

```
//loads data into recycler view onstart up
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>()
                    .setQuery(dbReference, Data.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, DataViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

            return new DataViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {
            // Bind the image_details object to the BlogViewHolder
            // ...
            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getDepartment(), model.getDescription());
        }
    };



    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
```