# how can get only item that I wanted in recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview I want to display post in recycler view ..what my problem is I want to display only posts that as **popularlist="true"** in the database...there are photo that I don't want to display[image] 
please take a look at database structure ..over here **popularlist="false" by default** by all photo I want the recycler view to check if the **popularlist="true"** it needs to display in recycler view if its **false**it should not display the photo ....can any one please tell me how can I do this ...

```
      @Override
public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
    int viewType;
    if (moviesList.get(position).getType_post().contains("Photo") ) {

            viewType = IMAGE_TYPE;
    } else if(moviesList.get(position).getType_post().contains("Video")){
        viewType = VIDEO_TYPE;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

I used this code for checking photo or video ...I don't know about filtering

**what I have tried**
I created an interface as listviewmodel below

```
    interface ListViewModel {
    int VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO = 1;
    int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    int getViewType();

   }
```

and created 2 model class called photoviewmodel and videoviewmodel which extends listviewmodel

```
   class PhotoViewModel implements ListViewModel{

String image_path;

public PhotoViewModel(String image_path) {
    this.image_path = image_path;
}
@Override
public int getViewType() {
    return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
}
}
```

in fragment where I get photo I add this code where recycler view is in

```
       List<ListViewModel> listViewModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Photo photo : photos) {
                    if(photo.getPopularlist().contains("true")){
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Photo")){
                            List<PhotoViewModel> pho = new ArrayList<>();
                            PhotoViewModel p = new PhotoViewModel();
                            p.setImagePath(photo.getImage_path());
                            pho.add(p);

                            listViewModels.add(new PhotoViewModel(photo.getImage_path(),photo.getDescription(),photo.getDate_created()));
                           // Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: alphs"+photoViewModel1.getImagePath());

                        }
                        if(photo.getType_post().equals("Video")){
                            listViewModels.add(new VideoViewModel(photo.getImage_path()));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**it display the body but I am not getting image path and other thing which I have add in fragment over here**

Comment: Please share your code... In major terms, you need to create an Adapter with the item list data. Before sending all data to Adapter just check for popularlist var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a query:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query=ref.orderByChild("popularlist").equalTo(true);
```

Then you will be able to retrieve the data that only has `popularlist=true`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: can you tell me where should I add this,,...should I add this in adapter??

Comment: Since you are using Firebase, then use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter since it is easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585134/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradapter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849

Comment: bro thanks for you answer but I have two view type video and photo ... bro does this filter out other photos which don't have **popularlist="false"**