# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have problem with Firebase Recycler Adapter. I am following this tutorial [Food Order Tutorial](https://youtu.be/dJm7LACOn80?t=30m33s).
When I create `loadMenu()` method and following the steps one by one, Recycler Adapter didn't work exactly same as in video so here's my code.

Can someone help me?

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Init firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //Set Name for User
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navHeaderTitle);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());


        //Load Menu
        recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reculer_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadMenu();
    }

        private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {

            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder,Category model, int position){
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);

                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you shared?

Comment: new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) 
red line appear under this

Comment: it tells me this error: constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<T,VH> cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category>
found: Class<Category>,int,Class<MenuViewHolder>,DatabaseReference
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T,VH are type-variables:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
when i run it

Comment: edit your question and please Add FirebaseRecyclerAdapter class

Comment: Thanks for update. Can you please add the information to the question itself, by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50786108/edit) link right under it?

Comment: Aside from that: the signature of the constructor has changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091837/firebaserecycleradapter-cannot-be-applied-to-firebaserecycleradapter