# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

```
private void loadMenu() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().setQuery(category,Category.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, int position, Category model) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem=model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, ""+clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: please help me to solve this there is error in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: please elaborate more on your issue

Comment: Please add more information about where exactly is the problem and whats the exact error message.

Comment: me added one image please check that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091837/firebaserecycleradapter-cannot-be-applied-to-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: @John Joe it still not working same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, you are giving wrong arguments. Since you already using the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                    .setQuery(MenuViewHolder, Category.class)
                    .build();
```

so just change that line to this

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
```