# Getting Data from firebase and binding to recycler view

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

First im using this version of database  : implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
Im trying this code and getting error at the bold statement error is : Expected 1 arguments but found 4.
code is :
private void loadMenu() {

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>**(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category)** {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    }}
```

***Edited one :***
private void loadMenu() {

```
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                .setQuery(category,Category.class)
                .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent,false);
            return   new MenuViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
            viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem=model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener...

            }


        }
    };
}
```

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public TextView txtMenuName;
public ImageView imageView;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txtMenuName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
    imageView= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (3.x) of FirebaseUI implements a different method of initializing a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter than previous versions. From the using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter documentation:

First, configure the adapter by building FirebaseRecyclerOptions. In this case we will continue with our chat example:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
                        .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
                        .build();
```

Next create the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter object. You should already have a ViewHolder subclass for displaying each item.

So, for your example, you'll need to do something similar to:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<image_details> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<image_details>()
                .setQuery(myRef, image_details.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<image_details, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false);

        return new BlogViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, image_details model) {
        // Bind the image_details object to the BlogViewHolder
        // ...
    }
};
```

Finally, the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call adapter.startListening() and adapter.stopListening() to stop the listener. It's recommended to call these in onStart() and onStop() respectively. Further details on this are available in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter lifecycle documentation. taken from: [firebaserecycleradapter() cannot be applied to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091837/firebaserecycleradapter-cannot-be-applied-to-firebaserecycleradapter)

Comment: Thanks this worked , but its not letting me to setIemClickListener

Comment: does your view holder class extend view holder?

Comment: yea its showing viewholder but when i continue viewholder.setItemClickListener it gives error . Knowing that i have interface  setItemClickListener code : public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onClick(View view,int position,boolean isLongClick);
}

Comment: could you post your MenuViewHolder.java?

Comment: public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


    public TextView txtMenuName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtMenuName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        imageView= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}

Comment: could you post it in the question? I can't really read this...

Comment: posted can you figure it out please im stuck

Comment: did you try setting onclick on viewholder.itemview?

Comment: u mean this trying this : viewHolder.itemView ?